# How can I require authentication for anything under /admin path?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask

I'm using Flask and I'd like to protect everything under /admin path.

How can I do that? I'm sure there's a better way than checking for the session in every function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this, I think, is to use a Blueprint similar to how it is described [in this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/59/). Then you can have some code that will run before each request when the URL starts with `/admin`, and within that code you can do your authentication.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way would be to write a decorator that tests the session, and redirects to another page if the authentication fails. I don't know how much python you know, but a decorator is a function that takes a function and returns another function. Basically, it's a function modifier. Here's a decorator that should show you the way to writing your own to check the session:

```
import functools

def check_session(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if <test for auth>:
            return view(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return flask.redirect("/")
    return inner
```

As you can see, we have a function that takes the view function, and then defines a new function called inner which checks for authentication, and if it succeeds, calls the original view. The line `@functools.wraps(view)` is an example of using a decorator; the `functools.wraps` decorator gives the function it is wrapping the properties of the function that it is given as it's first argument. To use this decorator, apply it to your views as such:

```
@app.route("/admin")
@check_session
def admin_view():
    return "Top secret"
```

Any user who fails the authentication check will now be redirected away, and users who do will be able to see the view as usual. Decorators are applied in a bottom to top order, so make sure that you put it after any other decorators that do function registration (i.e. `@app.route`).

Comment: I'm a beginner in Python. I understand using your method, I'll have to put @check_session decorator in every function definition under /admin and it's not possible to put it in one place only. Is that correct?

Comment: While there might be other solutions that involve less typing, they are most likely hackier and harder to maintain. The good thing about decorators are that they are very explicit, and are at the same place as the function declaration in the source.